# Lambda expression - Select into is not giving the results of all tables specified in the joins

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using Linq Joins and is it possible to write the select without specifying the list properties. I tried select into but it is not returning the lists of all list used in the joins.

For eg,
I have a two classes like below
PayrollLineitems
PayrollDetails

```cs
public class PayrollLineitems 
{
    public int ExternalScheduleID {get;set;}
    public string LineItemName {get;set;}
}

public class  PayrollDetails
{
    public int ExternalScheduleID {get;set;}
    public datetime PayrollDate {get;set;}
}
```

### Case # 1

```cs
var res = 
    from PayrollDtls in PayrollDetailInfo
    join PayrollLineItemDtls in PayrollLineItemDetails on 
        PayrollDtls.ExternalScheduleID equals PayrollLineItemDtls.ExternalScheduleID
    into FinalResult
    select FinalResult;
```

FinalResult is having the PayrollLineItemDtls. So how can i get a finalResult which has both PayrollDtls  and PayrollLineItemDtls lists.

we can try select new {} but is there a way to return the list without specifying the each property?

### Even i tried like below
Case # - 2

```cs
var res = 
    from PayrollDtls in PayrollDetailInfo
    join PayrollLineItemDtls in PayrollLineItemDetails on 
        PayrollDtls.ExternalScheduleID equals PayrollLineItemDtls.ExternalScheduleID                         
    select new { PayrollDtls, PayrollLineItemDtls }
```

In the above case, it is not returning the flattened list.

### Case # - 3

```
    var res = 
    from PayrollDtls in PayrollDetailInfo
    join PayrollLineItemDtls in PayrollLineItemDetails on 
        PayrollDtls.ExternalScheduleID equals PayrollLineItemDtls.ExternalScheduleID                         
    select new FinalResult 
{ 
   ExternalScheduleID=PayrollDetails.ExternalScheduleID,
   PayrollDate =PayrollDtls.PayrollDate,
   LineItemName =PayrollLineItemDtls.LineItemName 
}
```

I can't specify the each Property as above since each class has more then 100's of properties. So is there a way without specifying the properties?

is there a way to get the final list in join as combination of both PayrollDetails and PayrollLineitems?

Final result expecting

### FinalResult

```cs
public int ExternalScheduleID {get;set;}
public string LineItemName {get;set;}
public int ExternalScheduleID {get;set;}
public datetime PayrollDate {get;set;}
```

Above is a sample class and each class may have more then 100's of properties so specifying each will be tedious.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Maybe you can create FinalResult with inheritance of other two items, and then use a `MemberwiseClone()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var res = (from pdi in PayrollDetailInfo
            join plid in PayrollLineItemDetails on 
      pdi.ExternalScheduleID equals plid.ExternalScheduleID into FinalResultsj
         from plid in FinalResultsj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new {
   pdi.ExternalScheduleID 
   pdi.LineItemName 
   plid.PayrollDate 
                     }).ToList();
```

or you can try this ( I only don't know how it could be usefull):

```
var res = (from pdi in PayrollDetailInfo
            join plid in PayrollLineItemDetails on 
      pdi.ExternalScheduleID equals plid.ExternalScheduleID into FinalResultsj
         from plid in FinalResultsj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new {
         PayrollDetailInfo=pdi,
          PayrollLineItemDetails =plid
                     }).ToList();
```

maybe you can use reflections to create a list of all properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't want to try above method as each class will have more then 100 properties and specifying each property in the select new will be tedious. So is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you mean, we do not need to list properties with this code.

```
 var res =from PayrollDtls in PayrollDetailInfo

     join PayrollLineItemDtls in PayrollLineItemDetails

     on PayrollDtls.ExternalScheduleID equals PayrollLineItemDtls.ExternalScheduleID 

                 select new 
                    {
                        PayrollDtls,
                        PayrollLineItemDtls  
                    };
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.